# How can I change the data in an aspx ListView from the server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have an aspx ListView in which I'd like to change the data from the server side. Here's the incomplete code with which the API will be called from which the data will come

```
 protected async void ButtonZoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vanRadius = "";
        if (hiddenVan.Value != "")
        {
            if (hiddenVan.Value.Contains("POINT"))//als er een geometry point wordt meegegeven
            {
                vanRadius = "PN|" + hiddenVan.Value + "|" + radius.Text;
            }
        }
        //ListView1.DataSourceObject =
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:26454/api/Kandidaten/JsonKanRadius");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?vanRadius=" + vanRadius);

            string kandidaten = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

The code is incomplete because I don't know how to get data from a result to a ListView.

Please, let me know if my question is unclear or incomplete.

Comment: what are you getting in response?

Comment: A JSON object, [
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "KandidaatDevice": [],
    "KandidaatNotification": [],
    "KandidaatOpdracht": [],
    "KandidaatCvDocument": [],
    "KandidaatCvOnline": [],
    "KandidaatMotivatieDocument": [],
    "KandidaatMotivatieOnline": [],
    "WachtwoordVergetenRequestsKandidaten": [],
    "VacaturesZoekopdrachten": [],
    "ErrorLog": [],
    "id_kandidaat": 30081,
    "voornaam": "Vincent",     And so on.